# Existence of $x_0$ in the exercise of Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $f,g,h$ three real functions such that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty}h(x)=0.$$

Furthermore, suppose also that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}=0.$$

My question is as follows: Is it possible to guarantee that there exists $x_0$ such that

$$ f(x)\leq g(x_0)h(x)$$
for every $x\geq x_0$?

Fixed any real number $x_0$ it is obvious that this is true for $x$ large enough, since $f$ decreases faster than $h$. However, I need the inequality to $x\geq x_0$.

I will be grateful for any help!Thank you!

Comment: I will edit and put $g(x)>0$, for every $x>0$.

Comment: You should not update a question with an existing answer. We can't shoot on a moving target! Ask another question in that case.

Comment: Okay, I'll leave it as is. But I'm interested when $g$ is not null.

Comment: $h$ must be $>0$. It fails if $f, g > 0$ and $h < 0$.

Answer (score 3):

$g(x) = 0$, $f(x)= \frac{1}{x^2}$ and $h(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is a counter-example.

$g(x) = \frac{\sin^2 x}{x}$, $f(x)= \frac{1}{x^2}$ and $h(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is another one.

Comment: Great. What if none of the functions are null?

Comment: Answer updated with a not always vanishing map.

Comment: Your second counterexample is false. Taking $x_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $\frac{1}{x^2}\leq\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\geq \frac{\pi}{2}$.